# What the maximum number of txout in a transaction?

Tags: protocol

I know the maximum transaction size is 500Kb.

I also know there is a maximum for sigop in a transaction (20,000?).

What I'm interested in is what is the maximum number of txouts you could include in a single transaction.

Answer (score 3):

There is no practical maximum number of outputs in a transaction. The number of transactions can be up to 2<sup>64</sup>-1, or 18446744073709551615. The transaction fee would be more than the total bitcoins to ever exist.

Comment: The maximum block size is 250,000 bytes (https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Transaction_fees).  txin is approximately 148 bytes, a txout is about 34 bytes. Assuming 1 txin then max_txout ~= 7348. However, I believe that calculation is also limited by the max sigop limit.

Comment: @GregHewgill how did you come up with 2^64-1?

Comment: @GeorgeKimionis: The number of transactions is stored in the Bitcoin block as a [Variable length integer](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Protocol_specification#Variable_length_integer), which has a maximum range of 2^64-1.