# Is there any software that allows me to make a single multi-recipient transaction?

Tags: client, payment, sending

I would like to do a payment to multiple addresses in the same transaction on a regular basis. The scenario is this:

- Collect addresses via QR or string (these may change on each occasion)
- Use all the collected addresses to send an equal amount of BTC
- pay an appropriate network fee
- execute only one transaction

I don't thing QT or multibit can do this, but I could be wrong. If not are there any other software that could do this with relative ease?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bitcoin-QT can do this.  When you click the "Send" tab you will see a button "Add Recipient" at the bottom of the screen.

You can also do it using the RPC interface, with the `sendmany` command.

Comment: Out of interest is there a limit? Could I send 500, 5000 or more?

Comment: @T9b this has been answered here: http://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/21284/what-the-maximum-number-of-txout-in-a-transaction

Answer (score -1):

You can do this with Electrum.
See [here](https://electrum.orain.org/wiki/Frequently_Asked_Questions#Can_I_do_bulk_payments_with_Electrum.3F):

> Can I do bulk payments with Electrum?[edit]
>   You can use the CSV import feature to make bulk payments. It can accept either a CSV file or CSV entered into a text box. The rough format is:
>
> ```
> "ADDRESS","AMOUNT"  
> "ADDRESS","AMOUNT"
> ```

Comment: Please take a moment to read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Comment: I know this answer defies the rules, but it is more or less correct.